# Why [ngClass]="{enable-dot: event.isDisable === false, disable-dot: event.isDisable === true}" does not working in angular?

Tags: angular

This code does not work in angular

```
<span [ngClass]="{enable-dot: event.isDisable === false, disable-dot: event.isDisable === true}"class="icon-badge">
```

Comment: because you forgot enclosed the class name between simples quotes  `[ngClass]="{'enable-dot': event.isDisable === false;'disable-dot': event.isDisable === true}"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure of what css class you have used. But the right way would be

```
<span [ngClass]="event.isDisabled ? 'disable-dot' : 'enable-dot'" class="icon-badge">
```

You can use a ternary operator to find if event.isDisabled is true or false, apply disable-dot if true and enable-dot if false

Comment: you need remove the "{" and "}". ngClass can be used in differents ways, see: https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass#description (you are trying use the `[ngClass]="stringExp"`>) well, the string expresion can be a ternary operator that return a string